# Computed column with group by in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe :

```
Page_ID   Volume   Conversion   KPI     OSBR
A          100       10         0.7    (10,12)
A          150       11         0.2    (10,12)
B          100       11         0.4    (11,16)
```

I would like to goupe all the Page_ID by OSBR by counting the sum  of Volume and Conversion , and the KPI should be equal the sum of Conversion devided by Conversion.

The expected result should be :

```
Page_ID   Volume   Conversion   KPI               OSBR
A          250       21         0.084(21/250)     (10,12)
B          100       11         0.110(11/100)     (11,16)
```

I tryed with this code :

```
subdata1=df.groupby(["PageId", "OSBrowser"]).sum().reset_index()
```

But the result for KPI is uncorrect cause it counted the sum .

Any idea please to solve it ? thanks

Comment: Are the values in `OSBR` real tuples or just strings that look like tuples? Try `print(type(df['OSBR'].iloc[0]))`

Comment: what do you mean by "*group all the Page_ID by OSBR*"? "*comuting the sum of Volume and Conversion*"? and "*sum of Conversion devided by Conversion*"?

Comment: I got : <class 'tuple'>  tahnks

Comment: @mozway counting*

Comment: Still, it is quite unclear, how do you get 400?

Comment: @mozway you're right, sorry i made a mistake. I just edit my post by fixing the mistake

Comment: Why doesn't KPI for B change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
x = df.groupby(['Page_ID', 'OSBR']).agg({'Volume': 'sum', 'Conversion':'sum'})
x['KPI'] = x['Conversion'] / x['Volume']
x = x.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> x
  Page_ID     OSBR  Volume  Conversion    KPI
0       A  (10,12)     250          21  0.084
1       B  (11,16)     100          11  0.110
```

Comment: I would also have taken this as my understanding from the question.

Comment: @AidanDonnelly me too but this is more a total guessing than understanding ;)

Comment: You're right @mozway, it was a guess, but 'twas an educated one as I played around a bit with the values and Conversion ÷ Volume seemed to fit the most the values the OP had entered :)

Comment: @Crpix so the original KPI values are completely useless? Next time please check carefully the question details before posting ;)

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach assuming the final KPI is sum(Conversion)/sum(Volume) per group:

```
(df
 .groupby(["Page_ID", "OSBR"], as_index=False).sum()
 .assign(KPI=lambda d: d['Conversion']/d['Volume'])
 [df.columns]
)
```

or with `eval` if the variable names are valid python words:

```
(df
 .groupby(["Page_ID", "OSBR"], as_index=False).sum()
 .eval('KPI=Conversion/Volume')
 [df.columns]
)
```

output:

```
  Page_ID  Volume  Conversion    KPI     OSBR
0       A     250          21  0.084  (10,12)
1       B     100          11  0.110  (11,16)
```